# Why does psql add a '+' symbol to the hostname in this user defined function

Tags: perl, postgresql, psql

```
map=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hostname()                                                             
RETURNS varchar(128) AS
$BODY$
return `hostname`;                                                                                
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plperlu';
CREATE FUNCTION

map=# select hostname from hostname();                                                                  
     hostname 
    ----------
     topiary +


(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl's backticks include the trailing newline so when you say:

```
my $hostname = `hostname`
```

you get a trailing newline in `$hostname`. The `+` you're seeing in the `psql` output is just `psql`'s way of indicating that there is a newline in the field.

You probably want to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) inside the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hostname()                                                             
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
    my $hostname = `hostname`;
    chomp($hostname);
    return $hostname;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plperlu';
```

I also changed the return type to `text` since there's no need to include an arbitrary limit and you almost always want `text` instead of `varchar(n)` with PostgreSQL anyway.

You might want to read up on the `linestyle` option for `\pset` in the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).